# Cloud Composer grpcio Python package

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

I want to update the `grpcio` package in my Cloud Composer environment from 1.23.0 to 1.29.0. How to do that?

Do I need to add it in PyPI packages in the Composer console?

Answer (score 1):

See "Installing a Python dependency from PyPI" here: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies

Comment: I tried configuring from console as per document and getting below error 
UPDATE operation on this environment failed 1 hour ago with the following error message:
An error occurred before the new web server image has been created.

Answer (score 0):

If your environment requires a specific package, it is recommended that you explicitly install the package to avoid issues due to package changes across Cloud Composer image versions. Do not rely on the pre-installed packages in the Cloud Composer version that is running in your environment. [1](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-package) [2](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/upgrading#upgrading_the_version)